# How to execute bash within bash command in Docker-MongoDB from host system?

Tags: mongodb, bash, docker

I wasn't sure how to word my title effectively. However, I am creating a user in my MongoDB instance that is running within Docker by running the following:

```
sudo docker exec -it mongodb mongo -u mongodbuser -p testpassword
use myDB
db.createUser({user: 'myUser', pwd: 'myPassword', roles: [{role: 'readWrite', db: 'myDB'}]})
```

While this approach works, I would like to achieve it all in a one-line command from the host system. Currently, I need to do the following:

Running this command opens up the MongoDB bash:

```
sudo docker exec -it mongodb mongo -u mongodbuser -p testpassword
```

After the MongoDB bash opens, I run:

```
use myDB
```

After that, I then run:

```
db.createUser({user: 'myUser', pwd: 'myPassword', roles: [{role: 'readWrite', db: 'myDB'}]})
```

I am trying to create an auto-configuration script. However, this part of the setup requires me to individually run these commands sequentially.

How can I achieve the above equivalently automatically without me manually copy and pasting into the new bash windows that appear after each step? The script is running on the host system.

Comment: Use the [--eval](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/#--eval-option) option.

Answer (score 0):

Would be one of these ones:

```
sudo docker exec -it mongodb mongo -u mongodbuser -p testpassword myDB --eval "db.createUser({user: 'myUser', pwd: 'myPassword', roles: [{role: 'readWrite', db: 'myDB'}]})"

sudo docker exec -it mongodb mongo -u mongodbuser -p testpassword --eval "db.getSiblingDB('myDB').createUser({user: 'myUser', pwd: 'myPassword', roles: [{role: 'readWrite', db: 'myDB'}]})"
```

Or write all commands into a `.js` file and execute it:

```
sudo docker exec -it mongodb mongo -u mongodbuser -p testpassword myDB create_users.js
```

Note, typically users are created in `admin` database. I don't see any real reason to create them anywhere else.